# What is the difference between the various ZODB blobstorage layouts?

Tags: python, zope, zodb

The ZODB blobstorage directory contains a .layout file with the string 'lawn', 'bushy'.

What is the difference between the various blob storage directory formats?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is explained here: https://github.com/zopefoundation/ZODB/blob/master/src/ZODB/tests/blob_layout.txt

FTA:

> ## ======================
> Blob directory layouts
>
> The internal structure of the blob directories is governed by so called
> `layouts`. The current default layout is called `bushy`.
>
> The original blob implementation used a layout that we now call `lawn` and
> which is still available for backwards compatibility.
>
> Layouts implement two methods: one for computing a relative path for an
> OID and one for turning a relative path back into an OID.
>
> Our terminology is roughly the same as used in `DirectoryStorage`.

It also explains the formats in detail.

Answer (score 2):

You generally don't need to worry about the layout; `lawn` is there only for backwards compatibility.

If you do have a `lawn` layout blobstorage (you'll get a warning in the log if you do) and want to migrate to a `bushy` layout, use the migrateblobs script; here is a buildout part to create the script:

```
[migrateblobs]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = ZODB3
entry-points = migrateblobs=ZODB.scripts.migrateblobs:main
```

Shut down any instances and ZEO servers, back up your blob storage and run the script on your blobstorage directory:

```
$ mv var/blobstorage var/blobstorage-lawn
$ bin/migrateblobs var/blobstorage-lawn/ var/blobstorage
```

`var/blobstorage` will then contain the migrated blobs using the `bushy` layout.