# How and why to set the layout type for plone.app.blob (lawn v. bushy)

Tags: plone, zope, zodb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between the various ZODB blobstorage layouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866646/what-is-the-difference-between-the-various-zodb-blobstorage-layouts)

I have a Plone 3.3.5 site that I'm migrating to plone.app.blob.  I just ran a test-migration and noticed that all the blob files get stored in the same directory in var/blobstorage.

On the listservs I've heard it mentioned that it's possible to select between two layouts: "lawn" and "bushy".  Lawn appears to be the default, with all files in a single, flat directory, while "bushy" organizes them into subfolders.

Is there a buildout option by which one can turn on the bushy layout?  (I've not been able to find any examples of this.)

What are the strengths of each layout option?

Comment: Note that there's quite a number of problems with Plone 3 and plone.app.blob. If you want to use blobs in production I strongly advise to use Plone 4 instead. Using blob's in Plone 3 is highly experimental and you'll probably waste quite some hours debugging problems that are all fixed in Plone 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is explained in: [What is the difference between the various ZODB blobstorage layouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866646/what-is-the-difference-between-the-various-zodb-blobstorage-layouts).

You don't need to worry about this; `lawn` is there only for backwards compatibility.

If you do have a `lawn` layout blobstorage (you'll get a warning in the log if you do) and want to migrate to a `bushy` layout, use the migrateblobs script; here is a buildout part to create the script:

```
[migrateblobs]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = ZODB3
entry-points = migrateblobs=ZODB.scripts.migrateblobs:main
```

Shut down any instances and ZEO servers, back up your blob storage and run the script on your blobstorage directory:

```
$ mv var/blobstorage var/blobstorage-lawn
$ bin/migrateblobs var/blobstorage-lawn/ var/blobstorage
```

`var/blobstorage` has then been migrated to use the `bushy` layout.