# Identifying Files in Plone BlobStorage

Tags: plone

Files in var/blobstorage can be listed and sorted by their sizes via Unix commands. This way shows big files on top list. How can I identify these files belongs to which IDs/paths in a Plone site?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866646/what-is-the-difference-between-the-various-zodb-blobstorage-layouts could be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no 'supported' way to do this. You could probably write a script to inspect the ZODB storage, but it'd be complicated. If you want to find the biggest files in your Plone site, you're probably better off writing a script that runs in Plone and using it to search (using portal_catalog) for all File objects (or whatever content type is most likely to have big files) and calling get_size() on it. That should return the (cached) size, and you can delete what you want to clean up.